# Calculate duration from log events

Tags: google-sheets

I have log-events with a timestamp like the following in Google Spreadsheets:

```
Date    Time    Event
8-30-17 8,42    Login
8-30-17 12,31   Logout
8-30-17 14,1    Login
8-30-17 18,54   Logout
8-31-17 6,89    Login
8-31-17 14,01   Logout
9-1-17  8,24    Login
9-1-17  12,57   Logout
9-1-17  13,43   Login
9-1-17  18,03   Logout
```

So essentially this is the date and time when a login/logout occurred. I now would like to calculate the logged in time for each date. Taking the `8-30-17` this would result in a total duration of `3,89 + 4,44 = 8,33` hours.

As a second duration I would like to get the total time between the first login and the last logout for a day. So again for the `8-30-17` this would mean a total duration of `10,12` hours.

Is it possible to calculate this with Google Spreadsheets or is this too advanced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided not logged in over midnight (and you can handle some repetition) something like:

```
=sumifs(B:B,A:A,A2,C:C,"Logout")-sumifs(B:B,A:A,A2,C:C,"Login")
```

(copied down) may serve, assuming you adjust the delimiter (`,` to `;`) if required and that your data is numeric.

[image: WA109340 example]

[SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your *other* question, you might try:

```
=ArrayFormula(max(if((A:A=A2)*(C:C="Logout"),B:B)))-ArrayFormula(min(if((A:A=A2)*(C:C="Login"),B:B)))
```

[image: WA109340 example for *other* Q]